# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property - in React child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a global variable declared in App.js. It is declared outside of my App() function in App.js.

I pass this data down as props to my child function using `plyViewed={plyViewed}`

The error I get is when I try to update plyViewed. For example...

`props.plyViewed--`

It seems read only.

What am I doing wrong?

```
export default function MoveButtons(props) {
  return (
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        size="large"
        style={{ maxWidth: props.buttonWidth, minWidth: props.buttonWidth }}
        onClick={() => {
          if (props.plyViewed > 0) {
            props.plyViewed--;
            props.board.current.setPosition(props.fenHistory[props.plyViewed]);
            props.setFen(props.fenHistory[props.plyViewed]);
            props.setSelectedIndex(props.plyViewed);
          }
        }}
      >
        <NavigateBeforeIcon />
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not how you change values that are passed from parent component. First of all variable has to be defined as [hooks](http://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate). You have to pass it to child component but you have to pass also function that will change it and later on you use it in child component.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-knog9?file=/src/index.js) I created and example that shows how should you do it.

Comment: I see your example is setting state, but mine is not a state variable.

Comment: @Jon why is it not? If you want to change it in react it has to be state variable

Comment: The variable is used in calculations and I thought that with state, the values don't update instantly, there is a delay. And therefore, this could lead to wrong values used in calculations.